# Append percentage symbol (%) to a String, if the string is actually a number

Tags: java, regex, formatting

I am new to java and learning the core concepts, came across a problem where I need to append % symbol to a string number, for example.

```
String st = "0.9" -> "0.9%"
String st2 = "1.5" -> "1.5%"
String st1 = "AAA09" -> Should throw an exception.
```

I tried with below, but no luck, will appreciate any help.

```
public static String convertToCurrancy(String value) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)%");
        String bigDecimalConvertedValue = null;
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(p.toString(), symbols);

        try {
            BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(value);
            bigDecimalConvertedValue = decimalFormat.format(bigDecimal);
            return bigDecimalConvertedValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well don't be a bad luck Chuck; make yourself a lucky duck; tell us what's got you in a funk. What happens now and what should happen? Also, how is a percentage a "currency"?

Comment: Why not just `text.replaceFirst("^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$", "$0%")`? No need for any exception. `%`  will get appended to numbers, the rest won't be changed.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing exceptions, you may add `%` to numbers only, and keep the rest of strings unchanged using a mere

```
String result = text.replaceFirst("^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$", "$0%");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6L0JGO/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?`  - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Inside the replacement pattern, the `$0` placeholder is used to refer to the whole match value.